# Send logs to ELK container from Docker containers (without Filebeat)

Tags: logging, docker, containers, syslog

I'm using the [SEBP/ELK Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/) as it appears to be the most suitable for quickly setting up application logging. Unfortunately, after reading through [the docs](https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get logs from sibling containers without the use of [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat).

I don't want to install Filebeat on each of my containers because that seems like it goes directly against Docker's separation of duties mantra.

TLDR; how do I get logs from my application containers to my ELK container?

Comment: I might understand your idea. I did a ELK image, you could try to enable the file input in logstash ```https://github.com/nguoianphu/docker-elk/blob/master/logstash.conf```, then you could mount the file path with docker volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEBP/ELK was the wrong tool to tackle this problem. Instead, I should have been using a project that spins up a container for each of the elements of the ELK stack: Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana. I found just such a repository on GitHub.

The [deviantony/docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) project combines the three ELK elements into a working set of containers. The great thing about this is that unlike the SEBP/ELK project, deviantony/docker-elk doesn't take an opinionated view about what features should be available and what should be closed off. In the SEBP/ELK project, the ability to write to port 5000 is removed and when you try to add it back via a custom logstash.conf file, the UDP listener ultimately fails. Conversely, the deviantony/docker-elk project just works.

Bonus points: This project also has a branch that includes X-Pack which adds a minimal layer of security out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filebeat` in each container is against `Docker`'s philosophy. It will be waste of resources, And have more management overhead.

You can use local log file via `logstash`.

Example config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/apache.log"
    type => "apache-access"  # a type to identify those logs (will need this later)
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

Now we have to make the log files local to `logstash` container:

If you are using `bind mounts` you can mount the same directory in logstash container.

```
sudo docker run -d -v /path/to/logs/:/path/to/logs/in/container logstash
```

If you are using `volumes` you can mount the same volume that contains logs to logstash too.

```
sudo docker run -d -v logvol:/path/to/logs/in/container logstash
```